VSS: Use of ASR bare metal instead of VSS_BT_FULL
Working with the Shadow Copy Service on Windows 10, I cannot decide what the difference is between a so called 'full backup' and a 'bare metal' backup. I wish to create a system disk image, including user data, (i.e. a clone).
Microsoft documentation mentions this as being possible using the the back up schema VSS_BT_FULL, but mentions no providers or writers to use it with. Windows Internals 6th edition notes that the in-box VSS provider supports only CoW shadow copies, not full (p. 177)
An alternative seems to be the Automated System Recovery writer that Microsoft mentions is useful for creating disaster recovery/bare metal backups. I am unable to tell if a bare metal shadow copy would include user data.
I have scoured the Microsoft volume shadow copy documentation, to find the details regarding included user data.
Which writer/provider matches my needs the best?

vssadmin list writers Lists subscribed volume shadow copy writers. You may test these writers but I don't see the Automated System Recovery writer.
